# Problems using getopt in C

Tags: c, getopt

I wanted to use getopt() to parse arguments supplied at the command line, but I am having trouble with very simple test cases.  I have the following code (which is almost, but not entirely identical, to that supplied as an example in the [POSIX standard definition](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/getopt.html)).

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int c;
    int rmsflg = 0, saflg = 0, errflg = 0;
    char *ifile;
    char *ofile;

    //Parse command line arguments using getopt
    while (((c=getopt(argc,argv, ":i:rso:")) != 1) && (errflg == 0))  {
        switch(c){
            case 'i':
                ifile="optarg";
                break;
            case 'o':
                ofile="optarg";
                break;
            case 'r':
                if (saflg)
                    errflg++;
                else {
                    rmsflg++;
                    printf("Root Mean Square averaging selected\n");
                }
                break;
            case 's':
                if (rmsflg)
                    errflg++;
                else {
                    saflg++;
                    printf("Standard Arithmetic averaging selected\n");
                }
                break;
            case ':':
                fprintf(stderr,"Option -%c requires an argument\n",optopt);
                errflg++;
                break;
            case '?':
                fprintf(stderr,"Option -%c is not a valid option\n",optopt);
                errflg++;
                break;
            default:
                fprintf(stderr,"The value of c is %c,\
                        the option that caused this error is -%c\n",c,optopt);
                errflg++;
                break;  
        }
    }
    if (errflg) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: xxx\n");
        exit(2);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Firstly, when I don't have the default case in there, nothing is output.  When I inserted the default case, and make it output the value that `c` has, I get `?`.  This is odd for 2 reasons.  Firstly, and this is what bothers me most, why doesn't `c` then match the `?` case which was specifically written to match this output, but rather drops through to the `default` case.  Secondly, the output of `optopt` is (for my input) `o`.  The `?` character is only returned if the option supplied does not match any character in *optstring*.

Comment: What command line are you using to get this behavior? What platform and tools are involved? I don't see anything like what you describe. The behavior I see is that if you pass no options or only valid options that the program will hand because of the improper test for `getopt()` being done with arg processing that Emanuele Paolini mentions in his answer. In valid options are processed as you expect (with or without the `default:` clause.  If the `default:` clause is added, the program executes it when it's finished processing args (and therefore doesn't hang).

Comment: I see the mistake I made in the while loop condition, and that solves the problem, but I still don't see why I was getting the behavior I mentioned, which exactly describes the output I get on my system. Im using the command line compiler of XCode, on OSX 10.9.1. No extra tools are involved, just the command line and a text editor.

Comment: I don't have OSX to verify this, but I bet the reason you see the behavior is that when `getopt()` returned `-1` there was no case match (before adding the `default:` clause) so nothing was output. The program would loop forever with `getopt()` always returning `-1`. When you added the `default:` clause, the `-1` result gets caught there. My guess is that outputing `-1` with a `%c` format spec gets displayed by OSX as a '?' since -1 doesn't correspond to a character in the codepage or font. Now you're confused - it appears that `getopt()` returned '?'. Try: `printf("-1 as char: %c\n", -1);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the `while` loop condition you should check the return value of getopt against -1 not 1. Then if you pass the option `-?` on the command line, it should be recognized.